# Retrieving values from dicts

Tags: python, api, dictionary

Sorry brand new to python so this may be really simple.
I'm trying to retrieve a key value from a dictionary based on the users input. I'm currently trying an if/else statements but have also tried a for loop. My code is below, I just can't seem to find out why it isn't working.

```
import requests
import os
import json

orgUrl = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

payload = None

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key": os.environ.get('MERAKI_DASHBOARD_API_KEY')
}

orgResponse = requests.request('GET', orgUrl, headers=headers, data = payload)

orgResponseJson = orgResponse.json()
#print(orgResponseJson)

orgName = input("Please enter organisation name \n")

if orgName == (orgResponseJson.index['name']):
    print (orgResponseJson.index['id'])
else:
    print("Organisation does not exist")
```

If there's any study material out there someone could suggest that would be appreciated. The code is formatted correctly in the IDE but for some reason it hasn't copied across that way.

So I can't show the contents of the dictionary as it is business sensitive information but as an example the values are along the lines of {'name': business 1'}, 'id': 8384965'}}

So the code runs, it prints out the input, doesn't return the value 'id' and then continues to print out the else statement.

I guess it's moved onto the else statement because the if statement isn't looking in the dict?

************* UPDATE *****************
I've solved it. Whether it's best practice or not is another issue. I opted to use a for loop using the break command;

'''p
for orgLicense in orgResponseJson:
if orgName == (orgLicense['name']):
print(orgLicense['licensing'])
break
else:
orgName != (orgLicense['name'])
print("Organisation does not exist")
break
''''

Thank-you

Jake

Comment: What does not working mean? Please edit your question and provide: The contents of your dictionary, the input you are giving and what the program prints as result.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to check orgName which you've declared as an input. An Input returns a string value and therefore you cannot test conditionals for dictionary key values in a string in this way.

Comment: Hey, Appreciate the feedback. So how would you pull the info out of the dict? Is there a similar command for this like declaring a str as an integer when using numbers?